# Joining samba-ad-dc domain only working on Mac and not working on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mac, samba, domain

I have tried purging, reinstalling, removing, and everything else short of reinstalling ubuntu but keep coming across this error.

I am trying to setup a domain controller with samba and have set up the server on an old computer of mine. I have dns correctly setup on both my mac and my windows 10 pc where I can successfully ping my domain controller at both "doco1" and "doco1.euthena.net". However when I try to join my windows 10 pc to the domain. It gives me a couple errors. The first is when I enter what I thought was the correct link -> doco1.euthena.net, yet it gives me the error below:
[Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPFhL.png)

The solution to at least getting to the login screen was to just put "euthena" into the "Member of: Domain" box. However I end up getting an error whether I type the correct password or not as shown below:
[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/out6r.png)

Meanwhile, on my mac, everything seems to be working like it is supposed to. I go to users -> login options -> network account server. Then I entered "doco1.euthena.net" into the server box. Entered my administrator username and password. Any my mac now is connected to what it is labeling as "EUTHENA".

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: You have defined a DNS entry for *doco1.euthena.net* I presume?

Comment: Yes, I can ping that machine from both systems.